# Why does Visual Studio not complain when I write Console.WriteLine?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I was recently watching tutorials on C# where they mentioned that specifying either `using System` and then using `Console.WriteLine` or writing `System.Console.WriteLine` if you don't specify `using <namespace>` was necessary for proper namespace resolution to happen when writing programs otherwise the compilation would fail.
But when I'm using Visual Studio 2022, `Console.WriteLine` seems to work without specifying any namespace at all.

Is this some optimisation that Visual Studio 2022 does? Why is this working?
On top of this, if I use `System.Console.WriteLine`, VS 2022 also greys out `System` and says "name can be simplified".

Comment: This is *only* for the .NET 6 and later, read up on [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements) for an explanation of the change. It is also available in F#, but I am unsure if its in VB as well

Comment: I'm going to guess you created a new .NET 6 project ? Open the .csproj file, you should see `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>`. That is what is saying to Visual Studio (and msbuild) to add some of the most common usings.

Comment: if you create a new C# project of some sort in visual studio, it will automatically include the `using System;` line at the top of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;

  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create c# project of asp.netframrwork. It will automatically generate the "using System" namespace.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic; 
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp2
   {
       internal class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
         {

       
         }    
      }
   }
```

If your console project is .NET 6 and above. Please refer to [Exploring Ideas to Build Code While Learning Using Top-Level Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements).

Hope it helps you.